# Safe way to show only link from user post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xss, autolink

I'm trying to permit to users to post links in their posts. I use auto_link gem.

Is it safe in this way from xss and other attacks?

```
def show_content(content_with_links)
    auto_link (sanitize content_with_links.join(" "), tags: %w(a))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [README](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink), it is protected from malicious scripts:

```
auto_link("Go to http://www.rubyonrails.org <script>Malicious code!</script>")
# => "Go to <a href=\"http://www.rubyonrails.org\">http://www.rubyonrails.org</a> "
```

Comment: So I don't need to put sanitize method with  tags: %w(a) ?

Comment: You can use one thing or another. I mean, use `sanitize(string, tags: %w(a))` or `auto_link(string)`. Maybe the `sanitize` is preferable so you don't need to use an external gem.